# Select the last cell in a Word table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to figure out a way to select the last cell in a table in word. I have a document that auto-generates with one table, in which all blank cells are merged into an empty column in the bottom-right. Is there code that can select the bottom-right cell in a table?

Answer (score 2):

As your table contains merged cells you may find that referring to the column count gives you an error.

Use this instead:

```
Private Sub SelectLastCell()
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Last
        .Cells(.Cells.Count).Range.Select
    End With
End Sub
```

**Edit**:

To select the last cell of the last column simply reverse the logic, like so:

```
Private Sub SelectLastCell()
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns.Last
        .Cells(.Cells.Count).Range.Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This one didn't quite solve what I was looking for... the merged cells are merged vertically and it's selecting the cell in the last ROW... rather than the last cell in the last COLUMN... there are no horizontally merged cells though, so I kind of found something that may work but I need more help solving from where I'm at... I was thinking of using a rows.count-1,columns.count... but if it's more than the last two cells (Which it will be sometimes) it will fail. How can I tell it to try that, and if successful perform an operation and if it fails try rows.count-3 and so on?